# php script to get data from database android

Tags: php, mysql

i m trying to build a JSON array from mysql. it does not get the information from mysql

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$pwd="";
$user="root";
$db="mydb";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect'); 
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
echo"failded to connect";
}
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from product");
if ($query)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $flag[] = $row;

    }
  print(json_encode($flag));


}
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\new\count.php on line 19

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which one is line 19?

Comment: print(json_encode($flag));

Comment: It must be `$flag = $row;` instead of `$flag[] = $row;` as `$row` is already an array I reckon.

Comment: please specify line 19... where is line 19?

Comment: print_r($flag).. try this ..

Comment: the result must be Something like that  
 [{"image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.104:81\/new\/image\/laVacheQui‌​Rit.jpg","namee":"la vache qui rit","rank":"190","realName":"fromage vache ","createdBy":"danone","Appearance":"1900","powers":"190"}]

Answer (score 2):

Please initialize  $flag something like this `$flag = array()`

hope it was helpful to you.

Comment: This won't solve the problem though. It will just remove the warning of uninitialized variable. Please update the answer as its not resolving the issue

Answer (score 1):

change print to print_r(json_encode($flag)) you won't get any error

Comment: write print_r($row) inside loop and check if it shows something then also if not then check database that contains data or not

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your `array` to a `json array` so you have to use `var_dump` or `print_r()`.

Comment: the result must be Something like that 
[{"image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.104:81\/new\/image\/laVacheQuiRit.jpg","namee":"la vache qui rit","rank":"190","realName":"fromage vache ","createdBy":"danone","Appearance":"1900","powers":"190"}]

Comment: @HamzaAy What is the output if you replace `print` with `var_dump`?

Comment: Something like thatarray (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'http://192.168.100.93:81/new/categorie/boisson.jpg' (length=50)
      'image' => string 'http://192.168.100.93:81/new/categorie/boisson.jpg' (length=50)
      1 => string 'Boisson' (length=7)
      'categorie' => string 'Boisson' (length=7)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
      'quantite' => string '2' (length=1)